# How to load a partial view in dynamically created tab on a view without using Iframe concept

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-easyui

I have left link in my project and i want to create tab dynamically and load a view or partial view in the same tab while click on left link.

Answer (score 0):

on click of left link,

```
$('#tt').tabs('add',{   
    options: {
        title: 'New Title',
        href: '/vieworPartialViewUrl'  
    }
});
```